# ui-grid grid menu takes a column space as large as column header

Tags: ui-grid

Why does I'm getting a grid menu with a space the same as column header? It's supposed to be attached from the last column' content (space)

Look at this screenshots

image 1:
[image]

image 2: 
It looks close but still takes space[image]

This is the expected output from their [website](http://ui-grid.info/docs/#/tutorial/121_grid_menu)

[image: ![enter image description here]

Comment: I think it's the `ui-grid-header-canvas` miscalculated width . I'm not a JS savvy, someone tell me how to edit this please? It's generated through embedded `<style>` which I can't find.

Answer (score 0):

This happens because you have different **gridOptions**. In your example you have `enableFiltering: true` and they have `enableFiltering: false`. With your configuration the input element below each header is visible and that's where the space comes from.

So, in order to fix this issue, either disable the filtering or write few lines of CSS.

Comment: Already tried that. It's the same, look at this [image](http://imgur.com/a/xr0Kd)  I made it `enableFiltering: false`  

I also disable my other CSS so the ui-grid native css is used